# Prove that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of finite order with integer coefficients and $n$ is an integer, then $f(n)$ is an integer.

Tags: polynomials

Prove that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of finite order with integer coefficients and $n$ is an integer, then $f(n)$ is an integer.

I'm not to sure where a good logical starting point for this question would be. Could someone please help me start the question off.

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean for a polynomial to have finite order?

Comment: Induction on the order?

Comment: well, I'm assuming that order of the polynomial could be anything - but it couldn't be infinite.

Comment: Sums and products of integers are integers.

Comment: I get that bit but how would i write that into a formal proof

Comment: To me, this sentence would be enough to convince anyone, as well as any grader. If you want to write down some mathematical formulas, then explicit your polynomial as $P=\sum_{k=0}^d a_kX^k$ where the $a_k$ are integers and $d< \infty$. Thus, $P(n)=\sum_{k=0}^d a_kn^k$ is a finite sum of finite products of integers, hence is an integer.

Comment: Okay.  thank you.

Comment: I don't think any such proof is possible because if any of the terms has a fractional or negative power, it is easy for the polynomial f(x) to yield a non-integer.